# Skipping nextInt without any nextLine - Java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Even though I'm not concerning with that `nextLine()` method, these lines of code pose a problem. I still couldn't figure it out why. I have checked other sections of my code and I come up with this part where I suspect.

```
    int value;
    int capacity;
    int choice;
    int testValue;
    int index;
    ArrayList<IntBag> bags = new ArrayList<IntBag>();

    choice = 0;
    testValue = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    while( choice != 9 )
    {
        value = 0;
        index = 0;
        System.out.println( "\n*********\n1.Create a new empty collection"
                + " with a specified maximum capacity\n2.Read a set "
                + "of positive values into the collection\n3.Print the"
                + " collection of values.\n4.Add a value to the collection"
                + " of values at a specified locaiton\n5.Remove the value at"
                + " a specified location from the collection of values\n6.Read "
                + "a single test value.\n7.Compute the set of locations of the "
                + "test value within the collection\n8.Print the set of locations."
                + "\n9.Quit the program.");
        System.out.print( "\nChoice: " );
        choice = scan.nextInt();

        if( choice == 1 )
        {
            System.out.print( "\nPlease enter the capacity: " );
            capacity = scan.nextInt();
            if( capacity > 0 )
            {
                bags.add( new IntBag( capacity ) );
                System.out.println( "\nCollection has successfully created!" );
            }
            else
                System.out.println( "\nInvalid capacity!");
        }
        if( !bags.isEmpty() )
        {
            if( choice == 2 )
            {
                int input;
                System.out.print( "\nPlease enter the value you want to assign(use 0 to finish): " );

                for( int i = 0; i < bags.get(0).size(); i++ )
                {
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                    if( input != 0 )
                    {
                         System.out.println( i + ": " ); 
                         bags.get(0).add( input );
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
```

It actually should seek for any input other than 0 (0 terminates it) however, not even getting closer that point, this issue began to occur.

Note: bags is just an `ArrayList` object which has a generic type of a class that I wrote. It basically represents an array of integers, I think it does not constitute anything about this problem.

EDIT: It skips the last `input = scan.nextInt();` line in for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: what's the issue? Any exception or error?

Comment: @almasshaikh it skips the `scan.nextInt()` I don't know why

Comment: That's because you are pressing return key after entering integer number.

Comment: @VerumInfiniti can you please post more of the code to help us diagnose the problem?

Comment: @EvanBechtol Here they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pressing return key after every number. So when you type number followed by return key, scanner treats number as one input while enter as another input and hence skips the next integer number.

You should either enter all the numbers in a line and then press enter or better use `nextLine` method and then convert that String into Integer.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate by posting in here. I have tried putting some dummy nextLine() 's to consume the line, however, It didn't remedy.

Comment: @VerumInfiniti  I would recommend reading in your inputs as strings (create a string called strInput    or something) and then using: input = Integer.parseInt(strInput);  This way you don't have to worry about the new line messing up your nextInt(); call.   You do not necessarily need to read all the inputs at one time. You can keep the same basic construction you have.

Comment: @EvanBechtol Still there is no change. Yet, when I change that `input = scan.nextInt();`  to `bags.get(0).add( scan.nextInt() );` it works fine, but It needs to be terminated when it is 0, so, If there is no other choice I have to put it in a variable.

Comment: @verminfinit. Stop using nextInt. Read in a string and convert it to an integer.

Comment: why dont you use `String input = scan.nextLine();` and then manually add it like `bags.get(0).add(Integer.parseInt(input));` and you could check for "0" string as well.

Comment: @almasshaikh exactly right. This I'd the best approach.

Comment: @almasshaikh Okay problem solved. thank you! Oddly, Integer.parseInt... have solved it now but the main problem remains obscure, anyway I appreciate both of your effort! :)

Comment: This answer is only relevant if the code calls `nextLine` after `nextInt`. If you aren't mixing in `nextLine` then `nextInt` ignores the new lines because they are white space. [Example](http://ideone.com/AELQxR).

Comment: @VerumInfiniti *"but the main problem remains obscure"* So did the answer actually solve your problem or not?

Comment: @Radiodef actually I just meant that problem is solved but  the reason why it happened like that remained obscure